# PDF to ppm save progressive jpg

Tags: linux, pdf, jpeg, pdftoppm

I'm trying to convert a PDF to jpg images, but I want the images saved as progressive jpgs.

I'm using `pdftoppm` to do this. This is the command :

> $imageExecCommand = 'pdftoppm -jpeg -cropbox -r 100 -f ' . $pageToCopy
>   . ' -l ' . $pageToCopy . ' ' . $localPdf . ' ' . SERVER_ROOT .
>   '/files/' . $hash;

How can I make the jpeg progressive?

Comment: [Pipe it through imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg_formats)?

Answer (score 1):

Use pdftoppm command
Then Iterate the generated ppm files, then run
convert Image.ppm to Image.jpg using imagemagick